# Why is the force on a cross section of a rigid body equal to the force over the entire body?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics, stress-strain

If we have a block of mass $m$ (distributed uniformly) and a force $F$ acting on it, the block would begin to accelerate with an acceleration $a$. Obviously, the mass of half of the block is $\frac{m}{2}$. But wouldn't this imply, by newtons second law, that the force on half the block is $\frac{m}{2}a = \frac{F}{2}$ since the half block is accelerating at the same rate as the entire block?

If this is the case, then why is it that, in a rigid body, the force acting on a cross section of the block perpendicular to $F$ is $F$? I would instead expect it to be an infinitesimal force $dF$ since we are dealing with an infinitesimal mass (because the depth of the cross section is infinitesimal).

This question is coming from wikipedias explanation of stress [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(mechanics)#Simple_stress). In particular, this picture:

[image]

Notice how the force on the entire body is equal to the force on each of the cross sections

Comment: The diagram is correct. In the original diagram F is applied to each side, so the net force is 0. Therefore, the net force on each section is 0. Since F is applied to the top, each section must have F applied to each side so that the net force is 0.

Comment: If in the original diagram there was not a force on the bottom surface, then yes the force in the middle would be F/2 so that each half gets a net force of F/2. The top half would have F on top and F/2 on bottom. The bottom half would just have F/2 on its top side.

Comment: @AaronStevens This still doesn't explain why the equal and opposite forces on the cross section are $F$ and not $\frac{F}{2}$. It would be 0 net force either way.

Comment: Yes it does. See what I said about the top segment on my first comment. Tom B and I are essentially saying the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"...wouldn't this imply, by newtons second law, that the force on half the block is ma/2 = f/2?"

Yes. The picture is different than your scenario. The mass in the picture has two equal and opposite forces acting on it, so it does not accelerate. Note that the picture has no gravity.

Also, the force on a cross section in your scenario drops off linearly (given uniform cross section) from F at the end the force is applied, to zero at the far end, as you seem to have thought.

Comment: I am still confused at why the equal and opposite forces are $F$ and not $\frac{F}{2}$ or $dF$

Comment: Okay, remember that the mass in the picture does not accelerate. So the forces have to add to zero no matter how you slice it. Imagine the object as a string under tension F.

Comment: Compare the picture to YOUR scenario, where the force is applied to only one side. The object will accelerate, and the force on a cross section close to the end where the force is applied will be higher than the force on a cross section farther away.